# Find first, second, third, and so forth record per person

Tags: mysql, rows

I have a 1 to many relationship between people and notes about them.  There can be 0 or more notes per person.

I need to bring all the notes together into a single field and since there are not going to be many people with notes and I plan to only bring in the first 3 notes per person I thought I could do this using at most 3 queries to gather all my information.

My problem is in geting the mySQL query together to get the first, second, etc note per person.

I have a query that lets me know how many notes each person has and I have that in my table.  I tried something like

```
SELECT
 f_note, f_person_id
FROM
 t_person_table,
 t_note_table
WHERE
 t_person_table.f_number_of_notes > 0
 AND t_person_table.f_person_id = t_note_table.f_person_id
GROUP BY
 t_person_table.f_person_id
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

I had hoped to run this up to 3 times changing the OFFSET to 1 and then 2 but all I get is just one note coming back, not one note per person.

I hope this is clear, if not read on for an example:

I have 3 people in the table.  One person (A) has 0 notes, one (B) with 1 and one (C) with 2.

First I would get the first note for person B and C and insert those into my person table note field.

Then I would get the second note for person C and add that to the note field in the person table.

In the end I would have notes for persons B and C where the note field for person C would be a concatination of their 2 notes.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. The thing you're trying to do, selecting the three most recent items from a table for each person mentioned, is not easy in MySQL.  But it is possible. See this question.

[Select number of rows for each group where two column values makes one group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786666/select-number-of-rows-for-each-group-where-two-column-values-makes-one-group)

and, see my answer to it.

[Select number of rows for each group where two column values makes one group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786666/select-number-of-rows-for-each-group-where-two-column-values-makes-one-group/12789615#12789615)

Once you have a query giving you the three rows, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT() ... GROUP BY` to aggregate the note fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can get one note per person using a nested query like this:

```
SELECT
 f_person_id,
 (SELECT f_note
  FROM t_note_table
  WHERE t_person_table.f_person_id = t_note_table.f_person_id
  LIMIT 1) AS note
FROM
 t_person_table
WHERE
 t_person_table.f_number_of_notes > 0
```

Note that tables in SQL are basically without a defined inherent order, so you should use some form or `ORDER BY` in the subquery. Otherwise, your results might be random, and repeated runs asking for different notes might unexpectedly return the same data.

If you only aim for a concatenation of notes in any case, then you can use the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to combine all notes into a single column.

Comment: Thanks!  Once I saw your answer I remembered that I knew this.  I had gotten it in my head that I needed to do the selection down in the From section when it really needed to be done in the Select section.  But I also played around with the GROUP_CONCAT some and was able to come up with a single statement that will give me just what I need.   I appreciate everyone's help.  I'm an intermediate sql user working on getting comfortable with more complex queries and will be back I'm sure.